# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am running into the following error when running my tests. The condition for the test to pass is that the user must be logged in to create posts. similar errors seem to mostly do with foreign_key but I seem to have it. Any help will be much appreciated. thanks!

```
Failure/Error: @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
   unknown attribute 'user_id' for Post.

NoMethodError:
 #   undefined method `user_id=' for #<Post:0x007fe1d0bf19e0>
 #   Did you mean?  user=
 #   ./app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  ...
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
```

**rspec test**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Creating post" do 
  let(:user) { User.create(username: "user", email: "mail@mail.com", 
  password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")}

  scenario "successfully" do 
    sign_in user
    visit root_path
    click_on "New Post"

    fill_in "Title", with: "title"
    fill_in "Body", with: "body"
    click_on "Submit"

    within (".content") do
      expect(page).to have_content("title")
      expect(page).to have_content("user")
    end
  end

  scenario "unsuccessfully" do 
    sign_in user
    visit root_path
    click_on "New Post"

    fill_in "Title", with: "Second Post"
    fill_in "Body", with: ""
    click_on "Submit"

    expect(page).to have_css ".error"
  end

  scenario "User not logged in cannot create posts" do 
    visit root_path
    click_on "New Post"

    expect(current_path).to eq(new_user_session_path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like your test database is out of sync, try deleting and recreating

Comment: thanks man that helped

Comment: Ok - I added it as an answer so you can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test database is out of sync, delete and recreate it.